# Как ГИБКО наложить край буквы на рамку?

Tags: css, transform

Необходимо "хвостик" буквы **р** наложить на край рамки. Да так, чтобы при изменении размера окна, он не съезжал. Вот так должно быть при любом размере окна:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На данный момент в коде используется **transform**, но он уезжает при уменьшении окна.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 2;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  height: 100vh;
  list-style-position: inside;
}

.ramka {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 10px solid #A7A7A7;
  border-radius: 25px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.ramka1 {
  border: 6px solid #378383;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.one {
  font-size: 4vw;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.twotwo {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 7vw;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 0.08em;
  list-style: none;
}

.ramka11 {
  border: 6px solid #378383;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0 0.5em 0 0.5em;
}

.ramka12 {
  border: 6px solid #378383;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em;
}

.inline {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.ramka111 {
  border: 6px solid #378383;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0.3em 0 0.2em 1em;
}

.a {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: end;
  margin-bottom: -0.1em;
}

.four {
  margin-left: 1.7em;
  margin-right: 0.8em;
}

.five {
  margin-left: 1.7em;
  margin-bottom: 0.075em;
}

.one span {
  transform: scale(1.15) translatex(0.45em);
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css">
<div class="bordur"></div>
<div class="ramka">
  <div class="ramka1">
    <ol>
      <li class="twotwo"><i class="fa fa-group fa-fw"></i>Первый элемент</li>
      <div class="ramka11">
        <ol class="inline" type="circle">
          <li>Первый элемент</li>
          <li>Второй элемент
            <div class="ramka111">
              <ol>
                <li type="disc" class="four">Первый элемент</li>
                <li class="a"><i class="fa fa-sign-in fa-fw"></i>Второй элемент</li>
              </ol>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ol>
      </div>
      <li class="one"><i class="fa fa-home fa-fw"></i><span>Второй элемент</span></li>
      <div class="ramka12">
        <ol type="square" class="five">
          <li>Первый элемент</li>
          <li>Второй элемент</li>
        </ol>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте в стиль строчку `line-height`:

```
.one span {
  transform: scale(1.15) translatex(0.45em);
  line-height: 1rem;
  display: flex;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 2;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  height: 100vh;
  list-style-position: inside;
}

.ramka {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 10px solid #A7A7A7;
  border-radius: 25px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.ramka1 {
  border: 6px solid #378383;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.one {
  font-size: 4vw;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.twotwo {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 7vw;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 0.08em;
  list-style: none;
}

.ramka11 {
  border: 6px solid #378383;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0 0.5em 0 0.5em;
}

.ramka12 {
  border: 6px solid #378383;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em;
  background: white;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}

.inline {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.ramka111 {
  border: 6px solid #378383;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0.3em 0 0.2em 1em;
}

.a {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: end;
  margin-bottom: -0.1em;
}

.four {
  margin-left: 1.7em;
  margin-right: 0.8em;
}

.five {
  margin-left: 1.7em;
  margin-bottom: 0.075em;
}

.one{ 
  margin-top: 1rem;
  line-height: 1rem;
}
.one span {
  transform: scale(1.15) translatex(0.45em);
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css">
<div class="bordur"></div>
<div class="ramka">
  <div class="ramka1">
    <ol>
      <li class="twotwo"><i class="fa fa-group fa-fw"></i>Первый элемент</li>
      <div class="ramka11">
        <ol class="inline" type="circle">
          <li>Первый элемент</li>
          <li>Второй элемент
            <div class="ramka111">
              <ol>
                <li type="disc" class="four">Первый элемент</li>
                <li class="a"><i class="fa fa-sign-in fa-fw"></i>Второй элемент</li>
              </ol>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ol>
      </div>
      <li class="one"><i class="fa fa-home fa-fw"></i><span>Второй элемент</span></li>
      <div class="ramka12">
        <ol type="square" class="five">
          <li>Первый элемент</li>
          <li>Второй элемент</li>
        </ol>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Это не то. Вот что выходит: https://skr.sh/s5QAcet2DLl?a и https://skr.sh/s5QE0uCyh1l?a
Он не должен выходить за пределы рамки.

Comment: @224berryjuice так сделай `background: white` у нижнего блока, чтобы не был прозрачным

Comment: Так а это тут причём? У меня проблема в букве р, а не в прозрачности блоков

Comment: @224berryjuice У вас буква р залезает на нижний блок потому что он прозрачный. Не будет прозрачным, не будет и торчать.

Comment: @224berryjuice вы как бы поймите, у всех шрифты разные, разные браузеры, разные html-рендеры. Как бы вы ни старались горбатого с стенке ладнять, ровно не встанет! Если надо чтобы буква была четко на линии следующего блока, и во всех браузерах отображалось это одинаково, то надо отрисовывать оба блока на canvas или в графическом редакторе.

Comment: @224berryjuice отключите `z-index: 2; position: relative;` для `.ramka12` и будет заезжать буква, на этом примере

Comment: @МихаилКамахин Это если отключить: https://skr.sh/s5QwQ9gsEeY

Comment: @224berryjuice ну так transform: scale сделайте поменьше и будет нужный результат

Comment: @МихаилКамахин если scale уменьшить, то при уменьшении окна, хвост съедет https://skr.sh/s5QjJY4lz6S?a